# Bot freezing with Sympy (discord.py)

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, discord.py, sympy

I created a command to do math using Sympy. The problem is that if I put something that needs a lot of calculation (Like for example 9999999**999999) the bot freezes completely until the message with the result is sent.

This is my code:

```
@client.command(name="math")
async def math_command(ctx, calc = None):

    if calc == None:
        return

    try:
        result = sympy.sympify(calc)
        await ctx.reply(f"Result: {result}")
    except:
        await ctx.reply("Invalid")
```

Comment: This is because `sympy` is a synchronous library - it will block the event loop without yielding the control back before the calculation is over. You'll have to look into multithreading - by moving your calculations to a separate thread, you free the main event loop up to process other commands while the calculation is running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lukas Thaler said, `sympy` is a synchronous library and it's not meant to be used within asynchronous code, you can however use the `loop.run_in_executor` method to run it in a non-blocking way:

```py
import asyncio
from functools import partial

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  # in py 3.10+ use `asyncio.get_running_loop()`

async def run_blocking(func, *args, **kwargs):
    """Run any blocking, synchronous function in a non-blocking way"""
    callback = partial(func, *args, **kwargs)
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, callback)


# inside the command
result = await run_blocking(sympy.sympify, calc)
```

Comment: Thanks! You recommend doing this to all my synchronous libraries like json or is it not necessary?

Comment: No, it's not really necessary, I'd suggest doing that with the ones that take a long time to execute.